White boy and Peruvian boy attempt to solve a mystery in Cuzco, Peru
I am seeking the name of a movie from the late 80s, early 90s in which a white 10-12 year old boy from America became embroiled in a dangerous adventure in Peru.
He was aided by a boy of same age from Peru who entered the movie by running between each of the switchbacks at Macchu Pichu to wave to the tourists before collecting money at the base of the mountain.  
IIRC the film ended in the a set of ruins at Cuzco involving a handover of an artefact. 

This could be Max Is Missing from 1995 about an American boy's adventure in Peru after coming across an ancient artifact and partnering up with a Peruvian boy. From the TV Guide synopsis:

A product of a broken home, Max (Toran Caudell) isn't happy when he is sent to spend the summer with his journalist dad, Robbie (Matthew Sullivan), who's on assignment in Peru with his photographer/girlfriend Rebecca (Alexandra Hedison). When he discovers a tourist trinket in his knapsack, he doesn't realize that it contains a priceless religious idol and had been hidden there by a now-dead graverobber while fleeing his partners Becker (Charles Napier) and Velasco (Rick Dean).
Becker bribes street urchin Juanito (Victor Rojas) to pinch Max's backpack, but Juanito decides to keep it for himself. Circumstances force the two boys to team up after Max is unable to re-board his train due to Becker's presence. After surviving a plunge into raging river rapids, the boys discover the true value of their cargo when the golden idol is broken out of its concealings. Following the advice of a prophetess, the Curandera (Iris Peynado), the boys consider turning the idol over to local leader Great Inca (Reynaldo Arenas).

It contains scenes in Machu Picchu. Here's the trailer:




That is it.  Walt, truly impressive response time.   Many thanks.  :-)
